# Category-dependent custom permalink

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

My website uses a custom permalink structure of the type:

```
/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

Now, I created a new post category, which needs to have the permalink:

```
/guide/%postname%/
```

In order to do that, I added

```
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename)
    {
    if (has_category("Guide"))
        {
        $permalink = trailingslashit(home_url('/guide/'.$post->post_name.'/'));
        }
    return $permalink;
    }

add_filter('post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3);
```

This works, in the sense that if I write:

```
www.mydomain.com/guide/somepage/
```

I am brought to the correct page. However the URL in the address bar changes back to `/blog/yyyy/mm/dd/somepage`.

How do I prevent the URL to change?

Comment: look the hook `redirect_canonical` to cancel the redirection : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_canonical/

Comment: @mmm interesting... would you be able to expand? (I'm actually thinking of creating a custom post type altogether but I would still like to know the answer)